# Drying sedum. How can I save this plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

I bought this plant in the month of April. It looks like a sedum. It was very green and healthy back then. Now since summers started the plants branches started to dry though I watered it properly(not too much and not too less). Today I decided to remove the drying branches out. There were many of them. As I was removing them the whole bunch of it came out. I'm really worried right now. How can I save this plant? It seems impossible to plant it back because there are too many branches and they're very delicate too. Please help asap.. [image][image]

Comment: It is difficult from that photos. Could you describe better " the plants branches started to dry", before you watered. Are you sure you bought a Sedum for indoor? (or the inverse). Maybe it needs just some more time to adapt.  So: could you describe better the initial problem?